# How do I change Windows autocorrect?

Tags: autocomplete

I need to type the term `HSA` quite a bit.  Every time I do, it gets autocorrected (autowronged?) to `HAS`.  How can I stop this?

So far I found a bunch of autocorrect options in MS Office.  However, none of the rules there seem to apply to that case.  Also, adding HSA in the autocorrect exception list does not solve the problem.

What am I missing here?  Please help me before this drives me crazy!

Comment: What application?

Comment: If this is Word, normally you have in menu *File > Options > Proofing* the option "Ignore words in UPPERCASE" that takes care of such acronyms.

Comment: @essjae It happens in Outlook and Word for sure

Comment: @harrymc  That option is in fact checked, but it continues to autocorrect it anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under *File > Options > Proofing* in the *AutoCorrect* tab turning off *Replace text as you type* solved the problem despite the fact that there is no entry for hsa/has anywhere in the list that it is using.

One downside is that it has cost me the autoconversion of symbols (such as (c) into the copyright symbol.  In my case this is a tradeoff I'm quite willing to make.

Answer (score 1):

The Word option "Ignore words in UPPERCASE" should have taken care of
such acronyms, found in menu *File > Options > Proofing*, but it doesn't
work in this case.

This might mean that Office is corrupted and needs to be repaired.

To repair Office, run *Control Panel > Programs and Features*,
right-click on Microsoft Office, and choose *Change*.

Try first Quick Repair, and if the problem continues, then try Online Repair.

If the above didn't solve the problem, uninstall and reinstall Office.
Ensure first that you have its serial key for activation.

Comment: Quick repair didn't work.  Before doing the full online I decided to try randomly turning individual things on and off even if they seemed unrelated...  Hit the answer which I'll post.